# Canon MF8580Cdw won't print on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: drivers, 15.04, printing, canon

I have just switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 15.04.  I have a Canon MF8580Cdw laser printer.  It appears that I got it to install with drivers downloaded from Canon.  However, every time I try to print, I get the following on the page:

**** Unable to open the initial device, quitting.
                                              Unrecoverable error: unknownerr

Does anyone know how to get this to work?  Sorry to sound so noobish.